# Extract business description (Item 1) of multiple firms from their 10-K reports

Tags: r, parsing, edgar

I am trying to extract business descriptions of multiple firms from their 10-K reports using the R package, edgar. I am using getBusinDescr function to do so. However, I am only able to extract Item 1 (the business desciption) together with item 1A (the risk factors). Does anybody know how to manipulate the code of function "getBusinDescr" to only retrieve item 1? The parsing somehow has to end at "Item 1A. Risk Factors".

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on SEC filings for a while now for my research and my suggestion is to either develop your own scraper, which I don't advise unless you know what you are doing, or you refer to the Software Repository for Accounting and Finance from the University of Notre Dame. You can find the link [here](https://sraf.nd.edu).

People have already downloaded the whole 10-K filings coded as Stage One Data Parser. The full dataset is a bit heavy but it's already in plain txt so no hassle there. The only thing you need to do is to define some regular expressions to heuristically look for the beginning and ending of the Item 1 and 1A of the report.

Feel free to reach me out for more.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I already got all the 10-ks I need in plain txt and I was also able to extract section 1 and 1a from them. However, I fail to change the following section to also include "Item 1A. Risk factors" as a stop sign for the extraction..
  endline <- grep("^Item\\s{0,}2\\s{0,}Properties\\s{0,}\\.{0,1}\\s{0,}$|Item\\s{0,}2\\s{0,}DESCRIPTION OF PROPERTY\\s{0,}\\.{0,1}\\s{0,}$|^Item\\s{0,}2\\s{0,}REAL ESTATE\\s{0,}\\.{0,1}\\s{0,}$", 
      f.text, ignore.case = T)